# Animate a rotated line css?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I am animating a line from 0 to 100%.

**Keyframe CSS:**

```
@keyframes animate-line {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Line CSS:**

```
.line {
    animation: animate-line 5s infinite;
    background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    height: 1px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(16deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(16deg);
    transform: rotate(16deg);
    left: 20px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

I am using vendor prefixes everywhere in live code, omitted here for readability.

You can see I rotate the line with `transform: rotate()`; doing that makes the line veer up going from 0 to 100%. I can think logically why it is doing that, I define the left/top properties so I would think it starts at `top: 200px` and `left: 20px` and expand as expected but why it still wants to veer up ?

<kbd>[Running demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAdtU/)</kbd>

Hopefully someone can point this out, I'm sure its simple.

**ANSWER:** Just learned about a new property `transform-origin: 0 0` thanks to @barrett. It can be useful to animate a rotated line, and if anyone else is doing that using `transform-origin: 0;` is a huge piece, thanks.

Comment: Could you please write in 1 sentence what you want, because I can't guess it from the text you just wrote there.

Comment: I didn't vote down ...

Comment: Oh sorry, not trying to attack anyone, but its frustrating seeing a -1 within 2 minuets of asking the question. But I hope you see what I am saying, I always build a fiddle first, which I expect to explain it all. I was hoping that when I said the line veers up people would understand what I mean, because it's not really a natural animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet on `.line`:

```
.line {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

By default it will transform from the center which is why it moves up.

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAdtU/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/ZAdtU/1/ this is it. You're awesome, I was hoping to learn something new, I obviously had no clue it did that by default, this isn't something you see very often in tutorials or however you may have learned CSS. Glad you came across this question and spread the knowledge.